# Selenium Python find element by xpath returns empty list

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a table from a password protected website using firefox, before I can access the table I need to select the product, fill in the from and to date and slide to verify. I would like to only scrape daily prices.

I have tried the following code but it returns an empty list:

```
enter code here
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)              
number_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(), 'N')]")
for number_element in number_elements:
    print(number_element.text)
```

The code below also returns an empty list

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='tabTypeNav']")
```

I tried the code below but it scrapes all the other tables on the page expect for the one i'm looking for.

```
for tr in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr"):
    for td in tr.find_elements_by_tag_name("td"):
        print(td.get_attribute("innerText"))
```

Update, I managed to scrape the elements within the table!!

Table content was contained within an iframe so I used:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@class='tabBox']/div[@class='tabCont']/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]")
table.get_attribute("textContent")
```

Comment: number_element.get_attibute('textContent') try that

Comment: @ArundeepChohan thank you, I have tried that but it returned an error 
  

  File "<ipython-input-60-dfb342ffa108>", line 1, in <module>
    number_elements.get_attribute('textContent')

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

Comment: Which columns do you need to verify?

Comment: Hi @vitaliis I want everything in the table, the product, date and price

Comment: Check my answer. In general in should work. If it won't, play with locators. For example, try to change td:nth-of-type(2) to td:nth-of-type(3) to check the desired answer.

Comment: @vitaliis thank you I have tried to change it but it still doesn't show on my variable explorer and there is no output.

Comment: Is your table completely loaded during tests?

Comment: @vitaliis yep i tried during testing and a little while after testing i just ran your code but it still generates the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with definitions:
The `<tr>` tag defines a row in an HTML table.

The `<td>` tag defines a standard data cell in an HTML table.

The `<th>` tag defines a header cell in an HTML table. You won't probably need to verify its text.

First,  find all table rows (I made the locator more precise):

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".tabTypeCont:nth-of-type(2)>table>tbody tr")
```

If you need the first table, use:

```
.tabTypeCont:nth-of-type(1)>table>tbody
```

Second, find rows text:

```
for row in rows:
    value_one = row.find_element_by_css_selector("td:nth-of-type(2)").text
    value_two = row.find_element_by_css_selector("td:nth-of-type(3)").text
```

...

Then you can you them in a list or verify each one separately.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried the code but rows is an empty list, i'm using spyder and value_one and value_two do not appear in the variable explorer.

Comment: for debugging add temporarily time.sleep(5) before getting rows.

Comment: Thanks, i tried that it still returns the same thing, i also tried after the table has completely loaded.

Comment: .tabTypeCont>table>tbody  - than check if this locator is unique.

Comment: ahh no tabTypeCont is not unique. I have attached a picture of the table again, above the table there are three buttons, weekly and monthly also show tables so the locator tabTypeCont is the same for them aswell.

Comment: If you need the second one, I will update the answer. But clarify which of them you actually need, by count.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/accept the answer if it is helpful.

Comment: Hi thanks i need the first table with daily prices, i tried rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".tabTypeCont:nth-of-type(1)>table>tbody") for row in rows:
    value_one = row.find_element_by_css_selector("td:nth-of-type(2)").text
    value_two = row.find_element_by_css_selector("td:nth-of-type(3)").text still returns empty list i also tried ".tabTypeCont:nth-of-type(2)>table>tbody tr", got the same result as the first one.

Comment: How many classes .tabTypeCont are there? 3 or more?

Comment: more than 3, it's in the <ul> tag and script tag aswell as the div tag

Comment: What is the count of the element you need?

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean by that, but i need the table within the first div element in the 'html code' screenshot.